# How to load images in Keras when labels are also images?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a model for image matting. The training and test set images are of same size. And I want to load images from directory in Keras. My directory for training set is like this:

```
├───image
│       0000_1.png
│       0000_2.png
│       ...
├───label
│       0000_1.png
│       0000_2.png
│       ...
```

Test set directory is similar. All input images are in one folder, so I cannot use flow_from_directory. And when using flow_from_dataframe, I cannot give the directory of labels  as y_col parameter.

How can I load input images and corresponding output images as labels to train my cnn in Keras?

Comment: I think you'll have to write custom data generators in keras that will read your directories and provide batches of X and y pairs - in your case  y is also an image. (Look up "keras custom generator")

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks. Problem solved.